# List doesn't get updated in custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I have a custom control that inherits from a grid. In that control I have a list of ColumnHeaders (control that inherit from Label). But the list doesn't work.The ColumnHeaders are defined in xaml.

**Code**:

```
public List<ColumnHeader> ColumnHeaders { get { return (List<ColumnHeader>)GetValue(ColumnHeadersProperty); } set { SetValue(ColumnHeadersProperty, value); } }

public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnHeadersProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ColumnHeaders", typeof(List<ColumnHeader>), typeof(DataGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new List<ColumnHeader>(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentMeasure, OnColumnHeadersChanged));



<lib:DataGrid Columns="9" Rows="16" x:Name="mVersions" RowHeader="True" ColumnHeader="True" ColumnEnter="ColumnEnter" Background="Transparent">
    <lib:DataGrid.ColumnHeaders>
        <lib:ColumnHeader Content="Bedieningsb." />
        <lib:ColumnHeader Content="LCD" />
        <lib:ColumnHeader Content="Herhaalb." />
        <lib:ColumnHeader Content="Relais" />
        <lib:ColumnHeader Content="Printer" />
        <lib:ColumnHeader Content="Voedingscontr." />
        <lib:ColumnHeader Content="Redundantie" />
        <lib:ColumnHeader Content="WebModule" />
        <lib:ColumnHeader Content="Net" />
    </lib:DataGrid.ColumnHeaders>
</lib:DataGrid>
```

The function OnColumnHeadersChanged is never called. Why??But the other properties are updating the grid.

Comment: Use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`

Comment: ObservableCollection also doesn't work

Comment: Is there no one that knows how I can get it working?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnHeadersProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ColumnHeaders", typeof(List<ColumnHeader>), typeof(DataGrid),
  new PropertyMetadata(OnColumnHeadersChanged));
```

Comment: I get a nullexception without the default value, and with the default value the result is the same as before